# Using Jasmine-node to unit test Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When using jasmine-node (or any other JavaScript node.js testing framework come to think of it) to unit test node.js applications is it necessary to use the pattern:

```
//file-under-test.js
exports.some_func_of_many = function () {...};


//jasmine_node-spec.js
var functions_to_test = require("file-under-test");
.....
some jasmine tests here
```

i.e. does everything I need/want to test need to be exposed via the module object? It seems to me that I probably don't want to be exporting all the code in my modules...or am I missing some other pattern or something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to export everything you want to test directly. A common patten is to preface "private" methods with an underscore to give consumers of your modules a hint of what they should be using while still exposing it for testing purposes.

That said, there is a school of thought that says you should only export (and test) your publicly consumable methods, and let those tests "cover" your internal methods.

Comment: Cheers, Thanks for the speedy answer, coming from Java and pretty new to javascript, some things are quite different.